# Toggle js & expandible div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/8wKxY/153/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("#menu_categorias").animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        });
        var value = $("#home_categorias")[0].style.height !== "243px" ? '500px' : '500px';
        $("#menu_categorias").animate({
            height: value
        });
    });
});
```

I need that when you click the toggle button, the list remains in 343px of height, not 0. The list has a priori a fixed height, so I need that only when I press the toggle button the list expands itself and when it is open and I press the toggle button the list return to the normal height.

I think the problem is here

```
var value = $("#home_categorias")[0].style.height !== "243px" ? '500px' : '500px';
```

Answer (score 0):

$("#home_categorias")[0].style.height !== "243px" ? '500px' : '500px';

the code above does not make sense to me, it always set the value to be 500px!,

? '500px'(when expression is true) : '500px'(when expression is false) ;

so change this based on your requirement, it should work! like ? '200px' : '500px;'

Comment: Thanks, I made the change, but the button doesnt work when the list is open. I mean, The toogle works to expand the list, but it doesnt work to return the list to its normal height value. Please, could you help me with that?

Comment: what is the normal height value? 243px?

Comment: Yes, the only thing I need now is that the toogle button retract the list to its normal value

Comment: try $("#home_categorias")[0].style.height != "243px" ? '243px' : '500px';

Comment: try $("#home_categorias")[0].style.height !== "243px" ? '243px' : '500px';      Or  $("#home_categorias")[0].style.height !== "243px" ? '500px' : '243px';